# SQL query with all users and those not filled the form in the same query

Tags: mysql

I have table with the following fields

```
UserId, Username, Category, filledform
```

I want a query which should retrieve how many have filled the form categorywise.

Output should be something like this

```
Category  Usercountfilled  totalnumberofusers
```

I tried with the following query

```
Select Category, count(Category) from tablename where filledform !=' '
```

But I also want the `totalnumberofusers` of that category in the same query so that I know how many have filled the form and how many still pending category wise.

Comment: Please refrain from rolling back good edits, Raj. I have [asked this of you before](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61959112/revisions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So filledform is a space when it is not filled and not a space when it is filled...

```
SELECT 
  category, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN filledform !=' ' THEN 'x' END) as UserCountFilled,
  COUNT(*) as TotalNumberOfUsers
FROM tablename
GROUP BY category
```

A few points:

- case when will return 'x' when the filledform is not a space, and a null when it is. COUNT counts the Xs and ignores the nulls
- use COUNT(*) not COUNT(category) unless category is NOT NULL - any nulls in category would cause that user not to be counted
- please turn on ONLY FULL GROUP BY mode